# getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11) on realm query in swift

Tags: swift, realm

i have two models (User and Project) as below:

```
class User: Object {    // Users that logged in app in specific device atleast once
    @objc dynamic var serverId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var email: String?
    @objc dynamic var company: String?
    @objc dynamic var phoneNumber: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var syncBaseTime: String = ""

    let projects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Project.self, property: "user")

    convenience init(_serverId: Int, _firstName: String, _lastName: String, _phoneNumber: String) {
        self.init()

        self.serverId = _serverId
        self.firstName = _firstName
        self.lastName = _lastName
        self.phoneNumber = _phoneNumber
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "serverId"
    }
}

class Project: Object {
    @objc dynamic var serverId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var stateId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var stateName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cityId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var cityName: String = ""

    @objc dynamic var user: User?
    @objc dynamic var isOwner: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var isActive: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var compoundKey: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var syncDetailTime: String = ""

    let accountTitles = LinkingObjects(fromType: AccountTitle.self, property: "project")
    let notes = LinkingObjects(fromType: Note.self, property: "project")

    convenience init(_serverId: Int, _name: String, _stateId: Int, _stateName: String,
                 _cityId: Int, _cityName: String, _user: User, _isOwner: Bool, _isActive: Bool) {
        self.init()

        self.serverId = _serverId
        self.name = _name
        self.stateId = _stateId
        self.stateName = _stateName
        self.cityId = _cityId
        self.cityName = _cityName

        self.user = _user
        self.isOwner = _isOwner
        self.isActive = _isActive
        self.compoundKey = "\(self.user!.serverId)-\(self.serverId)"
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }
}
```

the problem occurs when I want to execute this query on them and get projects that current user working on them, but they are not currently choosen:

```
self.realm.objects(Project.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "user.serverId == %@ && isActive == true && serverId != %@", self.currentUser.serverId, self.currentProject.serverId))
```

I get this error with no more information from Xcode:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x11)
```

and I could not find where is my mistake and I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong specifier in the format string, `%@` is **only** for objects, and `Int` is not an object in terms of `NSPredicate`

Use `%ld` for `Int`

```
self.realm.objects(Project.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "user.serverId == %ld && isActive == true && serverId != %ld", self.currentUser.serverId, self.currentProject.serverId))
```

Note: This is Swift. Please don't use ugly *objective-c-ish* variable names with starting underscore characters. `self.name = name` does compile.

Comment: it worked. and I will consider your advise as I code and refactor